# Problems with htaccess multiple redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm struggling with the below htacces redirects. Some work, some don't work, and I cannot figure out why.

Every RewriteCond is there as these redirects should only work from the main domain and not from a subdomain I also have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.splendesco\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^workshop\-enneagram/(.*)$ /workshops\-en\-trainingen/workshop\-enneagram/$1 [R=301,NC] **this one works**
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.splendesco\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^workshops/(.*)$ /workshops\-en\-trainingen/$1 [R=301,NC] **this one works**
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.splendesco\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^workshop/(.*)$ /workshops\-en\-trainingen/$1 [R=301,NC] **this redirects to http://www.splendesco.nl/workshops-en-trainingen/workshop-enneagram/ which is not correct**
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.splendesco\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^trainingen/(.*)$ /workshops\-en\-trainingen/$1 [R=301,NC] **this one gives a 404 and does not redirect**
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.splendesco\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^training/(.*)$ /workshops\-en\-trainingen/$1 [R=301,NC,L] **this one gives a 404 and does not redirect**
```

**Edit**
Ok. I've changed things based on previous input. Unfortunately the problems remain :-(

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.splendesco\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? –[S=5]
RewriteRule ^/workshop\-enneagram/(.*)$ /workshops\-en\-trainingen/workshop\-enneagram/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/workshops/(.*)$ /workshops\-en\-trainingen/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/workshop/(.*)$ /workshops\-en\-trainingen/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/trainingen/(.*)$ /workshops\-en\-trainingen/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/training/(.*)$ /workshops\-en\-trainingen/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

By the way: if I use

```
Redirect 301 /training /workshops-en-trainingen/
```

everything is just fine and the redirects work as expected, except ... that redirects will also take place when on the subdomain.

Comment: I'd put the `[L]` flag on every rule so it doesn't check for others when a match is found. Just a thought. But I can see all `RewriteCond` are the same, is that normal?

Comment: I had it before with the [L] flag on every rule and the problem was there then also. All RewriteCond are the same: that what I learned should be correct, but I'm happy to learn that this isn't the case and that you can use only 1 ReWriteCond for multiple redirects. Tnx for your reply :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use only **one** `RewriteCond` for **multiple** `RewriteRule`

Comment: Ok. I've changed things based on previous input. Unfortunately the problems remain :-(

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.splendesco\.nl$ [NC]

RewriteRule .? –[S=5]

RewriteRule ^/workshop\-enneagram/(.*)$ /workshops\-en\-trainingen/workshop\-enneagram/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/workshops/(.*)$ /workshops\-en\-trainingen/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/workshop/(.*)$ /workshops\-en\-trainingen/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/trainingen/(.*)$ /workshops\-en\-trainingen/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/training/(.*)$ /workshops\-en\-trainingen/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: By the way: if I use

`Redirect 301 /training /workshops-en-trainingen/`

everything is just fine and the redirects work as expected, except ... that redirects will also take place when on the subdomain.